# Is there a function to get the list of nodes by type?

Tags: nodes

Is there a function like `node_load()` that returns a list of nodes by a given content type?

I've tried `$nodes = node_load(array("type" => 'student_vote'))`, but it only returns one node.

I know I could code up something like `node_load()`, but I wanted to see if there might be anything like that out there already.

Answer (score 46):

The code to use depends from the Drupal version.

#### Drupal 6

```php
$nodes = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type="%s"', $type);
```

#### Drupal 7

```php
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));
```

#### Drupal 8

```php
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'NODETYPE')
  ->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadMultiple($nids);
```

Comment: Yes, this would work.

Comment: Bear in mind that the $conditions array is depreciated and will be removed in Drupal 8, for future compatibility it would be better to use EntityFieldQuery (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) to get the node ids, then pass those into the first argument of node_load_multiple(). There is a good tutorial here: https://drupal.org/node/1343708

Comment: Just for clarity, EntityFieldQuery() is no more in Drupal 8.

Comment: D8: if you're writing some sort of batch task and you see 0 results for content with restricted permissions, you might need `->accessCheck(FALSE)`

Answer (score 13):

There is no such API for Drupal 6. The closest you can do is to properly query for all node ID for the content type then load each one using node_load() but this will require n+1 queries and is not very efficient.

```
function node_load_by_type($type, $limit = 15, $offset = 0) {
  $nodes = array();
  $query = db_rewrite_sql("SELECT nid FROM {node} n WHERE type = '%s'", 'n');
  $results = db_query_range($query, $type, $offset, $limit);
  while($nid = db_result($results)) {
    $nodes[] = node_load($nid);
  }
  return $nodes;
}
```

Note: [`db_rewrite_sql`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/function/db_rewrite_sql/6) will ensure access check and other module provided filtering (such as language filtering provided by the i18n module).

For Drupal 7, you can use `$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));`but the `$conditions` argument of [`node_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) is deprecated. Instead, you should use [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) to query for the node IDs then use `node_load_multiple()` but without a `$condition`s argument.

```
function node_load_by_type($type, $limit = 15, $offset = 0) {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', $type)
    ->range($offset, $limit);
  $results = $query->execute();
  return node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));
}
```

Comment: Actually, if you do a node_load() in D6 like this: node_load( array( 'type' => 'page' ) ) you will get all an array of all page nodes.

Comment: @bsenftner node_load( array( 'type' => 'page' ) ) only returns one node.

Answer (score 7):

There's several good answers already, but they take the question literally and refer to nodes only.

Since D6 doesn't have an API for doing what is being asked for, and it's not necessary to limit oneself to nodes in D7 and forward, I feel a good answer should be entity generic.

```
function entity_load_by_type($entity_type, $bundle, $limit = 10, $offset = 0) {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', $entity_type)
    ->entityCondition('bundle', $bundle)
    ->range($offset, $limit);
  $results = $query->execute();
  return entity_load($entity_type, array_keys($results[$]));
}
```

Comment: I was going to add an answer about `EntityFieldQuery`, but you have already written yours. I would just add that the second argument of `user_load_multiple()` has been deprecated since Drupal 7, and the used code should be the one you show.

Comment: I figured I didn't even need to refer to the old versions with deprecated arguments since I just used entity_load right away. That way there's "no" risk of people accidentally ending up using the deprecated functionality. Or do you disagree with that?

Comment: did you mean `array_keys($results[$entity_type])` ?

Comment: @commonpike Most likely, yes. I don't have the opportunity to check at the moment, but feel free to edit and correct if you test it out. :)

Comment: I was doing something slightly different and needed to specify `entity_load($entity_type, array_keys($results['node']));`. Havent tested it for other entities..

Comment: At the end, Drupal 8 deprecated both `node_load_multiple()` and `user_load_multiple()`, not just the last parameter they used. I would say it's safe to use that parameter on Drupal 7, since the code for Drupal 8 won't use `node_load_multiple()` nor `user_load_multiple()`.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8+

```
$content_type = 'article';
$articles = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties([
  'type' => $content_type,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end, Drupal 8 deprecated functions like [`node_load_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/8.0.x), [`user_load_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_multiple/8.0.x), not just the `$conditions` parameter they used. This means it isn't possible to write Drupal 7 code that is compatible with Drupal 8, as the classes used in Drupal 8 aren't available on Drupal 7.

Drupal 7 code can still use `node_load_multiple()` and its `$conditions` parameter. To load all the nodes whose content type is `$content_type`, it's sufficient to use the following code.

```php
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $content_type));
```

A more generic code that works for any entity would be the following one.

```php
$entities = entity_load($entity_type, array(), array('type' => $bundle);
```

Despite the name, [`entity_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7.x) loads more entities. It's the function used from `node_load_multiple()`.

```php
function node_load_multiple($nids = array(), $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE) {
  return entity_load('node', $nids, $conditions, $reset);
}
```